# Order a dictionary without using Linq OrderBy

Tags: c#, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to order a C# `Dictionary<int, int>` by its value without using LINQ's `OrderBy` as it's not supported on iPhones.

I can't seem to figure it out, so your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is a C# dictionary really supported on iPhones?

Comment: How do you mean iPhone? Which SDK are you using?

Comment: Why do you need it to be ordered by value? That's a requirement that cannot go together with a dictionary which is not ordered at all. I would suggest to use a different collection.

Comment: For everyone asking about iPhones and C#: [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/ios). Not because I want to promote it, but because it appears someone even voted to close the question because of this.

Answer (score 6):

There are many possible ways of doing this. All of the following assume `myDictionary` is the original dictionary to be sorted.

### ① Create a list and then sort the list

```
var myList = myDictionary.ToList();
myList.Sort((a, b) => a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value));
```

### ② Create an array and then sort the array

```
var myArray = myDictionary.ToArray();
Array.Sort(myArray, (a, b) => a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value));
```

### ③ Create a new SortedDictionary that has keys and values swapped

This solution is appropriate only if you know that every value occurs only once.

```
var mySortedDict = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var kvp in myDictionary)
    mySortedDict[kvp.Value] = kvp.Key;
```

### ④ Create a new SortedDictionary and use lists for values

This solution is appropriate only if values can occur more than once.

```
var mySortedDict = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();
foreach (var kvp in myDictionary)
{
    if (!mySortedDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Value))
        mySortedDict[kvp.Value] = new List<int>();
    mySortedDict[kvp.Value].Add(kvp.Key);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your input. I'm using Unity3D and I've only been using C# for a few months now. It's probably me, but my Dictionary's don't have a ToList() method.

Answer (score 0):

We can generate a `List` of `KeyValuePair` and then sort it using `Sort`,

```
      Dictionary<int, int> myList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> mySortedList = myList.ToList();

        mySortedList.Sort(( firstValue, nextValue) =>
            {
                return firstValue.Value.CompareTo(nextValue.Value);
            }
        );
        Dictionary<int, int> mySortedDict = mySortedList.ToDictionary(keyItem => keyItem.Key, keyItem => keyItem.Value);
```

I think `Sort` will be supported on iPhones